# Separating web page content so one does not affect the other

Tags: jsp, html

A bit of a silly problem, but I couldn't find solution for it. So, I have a jsp/html page with a `<body>` tag containing this:

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:130px;"> <!-- This is mandatory because I need to include header.jsp -->
<h2>Titles</h2>

<c:url var="editImgUrl" value="/resources/img/edit.png" />
<c:url var="deleteImgUrl" value="/resources/img/delete.png" />
<c:url var="addImgUrl" value="/resources/img/add.png" />
<c:url var="titleUrl" value="/essays/main/title" />
<form:form modelAttribute="titleAttribute" method="POST" action="${titleUrl}">

 <table style="border: 1px solid; width: 100%; text-align:center">
 <thead style="background:#d3dce3">
  <tr>
   <th>Id</th>
   <th>Title</th>
   <th colspan="2"></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody style="background:#ccc">
 <c:forEach items="${titleList}" var="title">
  <c:url var="editUrl" value="/essays/main/title/edit?titleId=${title.titleId}" />
  <c:url var="deleteUrl" value="/essays/main/title/delete?titleId=${title.titleId}" />
  <c:url var="addUrl" value="/essays/main/title/add" />

  <c:if test="${!empty titleList}">
   <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${title.titleId}" /></td>
    <td><c:out value="${title.titleDescription}" /></td>
    <td><a href="${editUrl}"><img src="${editImgUrl}" style="border-style: none;"></img></a></td>
    <td><a href="${deleteUrl}"><img src="${deleteImgUrl}" style="border-style: none;"></img></a></td>
   </tr>
  </c:if>
  </c:forEach>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="4"><a href="${addUrl}"><img src="${addImgUrl}" style="border-style: none;"></img></a></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>

 <c:if test="${not empty message}">
    <div style="color: #ff0000;">${message}</div>
 </c:if>

</form:form>
</div>
```

As you can see, not much formatting going on. My problem is, if `${message}` gets printed on the page, the whole content above it (html table with records) gets expanded to the width of the `${message}`, like this:

[image]

When normally it looks like this:

[image]

I don't want my table to expand. Can anyone help me on how to format data so it doesn't happen? Thank you.

I've tried using `<div>` tags to separate the content, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
</form:form>

<c:if test="${not empty message}">
  <div style="color: #ff0000;">${message}</div>
</c:if>
```

Basically put the message outside the form. My guess is the table is expanding based on the container box. If not, try setting a size to the table.

Comment: Message outside the form works exactly the same as in the form, but outside `<div>` doesn't affect the table, but then it gets garbled with the header.jsp content @beautifulcoder

Comment: Setting table width worked: `style="width: 200px;"` instead of `style="width: 100%;"`. Does this count like my own answer, or should I accept yours, I'm not sure...

Comment: And I don't like this solution. If content of a table cell is to long, line breaks and it looks ugly.

Comment: @just_a_girl, you can try setting `width: auto` I believe that will render the table width according to content.